# login-logout confusion (redirect to login page if not logged in)

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication, web-config

I am currently creating a web application, and for obvious security reasons I have to redirect anonymous users to the login page. Before doing some research, here is what I have for my Site.Master page:

```
[ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Logout.aspx"/> ]
```

as you can see, I've created my own Logout page which contains logout code, `FormsAuthentication.Signout` and such. There is also a Logout link in this siteMap which calls this page.

Now everything works just fine this morning. When I would click the Logout link in the `LoginStatus`, logging out works fine. I click the Logout link in my siteMap, logging out works fine. I tried logging in again immediately and the application redirects me to my default page. But when I added this bit of code here in my `Web.config`:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

something weird happens. I click the Logout link in the `LoginStatus`, and the app redirects me to the Login page instead of the Logout page. What's more, when I attempt to log in again, the app redirects me to the Logout page. That makes me have to log in **TWICE** just to be able to get back into the app again.

Why/How is this happening? any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've denied access to un-authenticated users to ALL pages in your site. You need to add an exclusion for pages that can be viewed unauthenticated.

For example - to grant access to home page for any user: -

```
   <location path="home.aspx">
      <system.web>
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

Some guides here: -

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/667473/ASP-NET-WebConfig-Location-and-Authroization-Tags

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prg.apv/usage-of-location-tag-in-Asp-Net-application/

Comment: how do I do that? If you could suggest an approach or something, it'd be much appreciated.